# View is not getting rendered backbonejs

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I have the following backbonejs code which fetches data in collection from my API.

**app.js**

```
var app = app || {};

app.Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
    photo: 'https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/10102369525962162085'
  }

});

app.Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Book,
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/products_user',
    parse: function (response) {
       return response.data;
    }
});

app.BookView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'article',
    className: 'white-panel',
    template: _.template( $( '#product_grid_template' ).html() ),

    render: function() {
        //this.el is what we defined in tagName. use $el to get access to jQuery html() function
        this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.attributes ) );

        return this;
    }
});


app.LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#pinBoot',

    initialize: function() {                    // UPDATED
        this.collection = new app.Library();    // UPDATED
        this.collection.fetch({
            reset:true});

        this.listenTo( this.collection, 'add', this.renderBook );
        this.listenTo( this.collection, 'reset', this.render ); // NEW

    },

    // render library by rendering each book in its collection
    render: function() {
        console.log('render');
        this.collection.each(function( item ) {
            this.renderBook( item );
        }, this );
    },

    // render a book by creating a BookView and appending the
    // element it renders to the library's element
    renderBook: function( item ) {
        var bookView = new app.BookView({
            model: item
        });
        this.$el.append( bookView.render().el );
    }
});

new app.LibraryView();
```

The above code renders the following HTML

```
<article class="white-panel r1 c0" style=
"width: 316.667px; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
    <div class="widget portfolio graphics homepage">
        <div class="entry-container span4">
            <!-- Portfolio Image -->
            <div class="entry-image">
                <a href="product.html"><img alt="" src=
                "https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/10102369525962162085"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="entry drop-shadow curved">
                <!-- Portfolio Heading -->
                <div class="heading">
                    <a href="#">My product</a> HII
                </div>
                <div class="camera" data-target="#prod0-modal" data-toggle=
                "modal">
                    3
                </div>
                <div class="price">
                    ₹ 10 <span>+ Delivery Charges ₹ 11</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

The whole HTML and data was getting rendered to the HTML and I found the why the was not visible was because, a style parameter 'style="opacity: 1;"' is not getting added to the `<div class="entry-container span4">`

The above app.js , I have modified to work, without an API as follows

```
app.LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#pinBoot',

    initialize: function(initialBooks) {                    
        // this.collection = new app.Library();   
        // this.collection.fetch({
        //     reset:true});

        // this.listenTo( this.collection, 'add', this.renderBook );
        // this.listenTo( this.collection, 'reset', this.render ); // NEW
        this.collection = new app.Library( initialBooks );
        this.render();

    },

    // render library by rendering each book in its collection
    render: function() {
        console.log('render');
        this.collection.each(function( item ) {
            this.renderBook( item );
        }, this );
    },

    // render a book by creating a BookView and appending the
    // element it renders to the library's element
    renderBook: function( item ) {
        var bookView = new app.BookView({
            model: item
        });
        this.$el.append( bookView.render().el );
    }
});

var books = [
        { product_name: 'My product',delivery_charge: '10.00',amount:'10.22' },
           ];
new app.LibraryView(books);
```

Now everything works perfectly, the style gets added to the div without any problems. The style is getting added using a fade effect javascript which is suppose to give a fadein effect to the grids, but when I fetch data and renders using the API , the div doesn't get added by the style element.

Why is this happening? Is it something to do with the pageload rendering or asynchronous data loading?

I am new to backbonejs, can someone helps me whats going wrong here when I call the API?

**UPDATE**

I have this script which is adding the opacity element to the div for visiblity

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         //<![CDATA[
            $(window).load(function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
                 $("#status").fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
                 $("#preloader").delay(350).fadeOut("slow"); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
                 $("#preloader-container").css("position","static");
                 $(".widget .entry-container").each(function(index) {
                     $(this).delay(400*index).animate({'opacity': 1},300);

                 });  
             });
         //]]>
      </script>
```

Is this script conflicting with my backbone data rendering?

Comment: Are you sure your API call doen't end in an error and responds with what you expect?

Comment: No i actually is getting the data in the view when I inspected the html, but the style element is not getting appended to the element and is the reason why it is hiding the element. But I am not sure why the style is not getting appended which but happens without an API

Comment: Where is this `style="opacity: 1;` defined? where is this fadein animation? Please share an [mcve]

Comment: It is a jquery plugin which is giving this effect. It is the one which is giving the fadein effect on the div. This is a huge html project which I wont be able to put in jsfiddle. If i am hardcoding my data its coming properly. The view is not visible when I use fetch from collection.

Comment: So you're `.entry-container` elements *after* the page has loaded and that's messing up your `opacity` setting?

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching your data before you bind the event for handling it. If the fetch ist fast enough this might cause a race condition.

```
initialize: function() {                    // UPDATED
    this.collection = new app.Library();    // UPDATED
    this.collection.fetch({
        reset:true});

    this.listenTo( this.collection, 'add', this.renderBook );
    this.listenTo( this.collection, 'reset', this.render ); // NEW

}
```

After setting up the views collection, bind all the necessary events and then do anything with it:

```
initialize: function() {                    // UPDATED
    this.collection = new app.Library();    // UPDATED
    this.listenTo( this.collection, 'add', this.renderBook );
    this.listenTo( this.collection, 'reset', this.render ); // NEW

    this.collection.fetch({
        reset:true});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried changing the code to the one you suggested but still not working :(

Comment: The ajax request is given away to separate thread and the js engine immediately switches to the very next line... The fetch has to success really really really fast before the js engine can even switch to next line which I don't think will happen...